# laravel xampp linux installation

Tags: linux, laravel, terminal, xampp, laravel-10

I have recently started he Laravel course and as I install the framework on my Linux distribution and /opt/lamp/htdocs I keep running into an error:

1. Debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
2. Curl: (6) getaddrinfo() thread failed to start
3. gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
4. W: GPG error:  https://launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease: the following signatures couldn’t be verified because the public key is not available : NOPUBKEY 4F4EA0AAE55267A6C
5. The repository ‘https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/phh/ubuntu jammyInRelease’ is not signed

Comment: I have tried solutions like

Sudo gpg –keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu –recv-key 4F4EA0AAE55267A6C

Sudo gpg -a –export 4F4EA0AAE55267A6C | sudo apt-key add –

Sudo apt-get update

 

But to no avail